# Converting Primary to Logical Partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I am dual booting Ubuntu on Windows 8, and during the install, I get no option to install alongside Windows 8. A previous question gave me the information that I needed to make my partitioned drive for Ubuntu a logical drive before it can be used in Ubuntu. The person who answered gave me a link to a program that you had to pay for.
Is there any way that I can change my primary partition to a logical partition without paying for a software? I am stuck on this final step in installing Ubuntu!!
Please be specific, I am new to Linux based software.

Comment: Could you boot using live CD, run `sudo fdisk -l` in terminal, then post its output. This will help to get answers.

Comment: Did you install Windows 8 in BIOS with MBR partitioning? Or is it pre-installed? If pre-installed you have gpt partitioning and gpt does not have primary nor logical. Just one type that is in effect primary but not limited to 4 prmary like MBR(msdos). Post this. sudo parted -l

Answer (score 2):

You need to make some free space out of Windows 8 for Linux.

For this, in Windows 8, go to `Disk Management tool`.

In the Disk Management tool:

Right click `on the drive` and select `shrink volume`.

You must leave the free space.

Now, you go to Control Panel ---- Hardware and Sound --- Power Options --- System Settings --- Choose what the power buttons do --- `Uncheck the Turn on fast startup box.`

You will have to choose `boot from USB` option from within Windows itself, pressing `shift key while clicking on Restart`.

Reboot and in Bios options, You must disable: `Secure boot in UEFI.`

Plug in the USB, the `Ubuntu Live USB` and boot the system from it.

Once you have booted, you will be presented with option to try or install Ubuntu. `Click on install.`

In `Installation Type`. Choose `Something else`.

You shall use the free space to create Root `/`, Swap, and Home `/home`, partitions.

Select the `free space` and click on the `+` sign.

Once you are ready with Root, Swap and Home, click on `Install Now`

Answer (score 0):

Also You don't need to convert your partition to logical(That was me!!) just delete your partition(**Warning:** be careful all your data in this partition will be deleted) and make it as unallocated space then try to boot Ubuntu from CD/USB and follow screen instructions. If you select unallocated space partition during installation Ubuntu automatically converts that to logical.

[free trial verstion](http://easeus-partition-master-professional.en.softonic.com/) of that software.

good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Download Gparted (it is free) and burn it on a CD (of USB). This CD is bootable.  Boot with this CD,and you can change your whole drive system.  download at http://gparted.org/